# Heroku toolbelt login with Cygwin hanging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cygwin

I'm able to access Heroku with Cygwin with an alias, adding the following to my `~/.bashrc`

`alias heroku='heroku.bat'`

This works, but when I try to use the `$ heroku login` command, it simply hangs forever.

I was able to work around this error using Windows Powershell, and barring a solution, will continue to do so while still on a Windows machine. Still, I would like to find out why this error occurs.

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit with Cygwin64.

Comment: Does the 'heroku.bat' batch file do something with commandline arguments?

Comment: Open windows command prompt, login, then close and use session on Cygwin

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get heroku working with cygwin on Windows 7 by installing the from the windows installer and setting ssh transport in my git config

http://www.railszilla.com/git-push-heroku-master-authentication/start

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadOf https://git.heroku.com/
```